# SAP Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2022

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am writing a VB.NET project in VS 2022 and I want to use SAP Crystal Report for reporting. I installed Crystal Report for VS and I also installed the runtime engine, but I still cannot add or edit a `.rpt` file

Please help.

I tried to reinstall CR for VS 2022 but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues when installing CR for VS. I was seeing the "binary file, opening in different application" in Visual Studio Community 2022 although I had multiple Crystal Report applications and runtimes for VS installed.

The application can be "overinstalled" if you install the run times. Also, you need to make sure that even if logged in as admin, you still need to "elevate" to admin. The following guidance was tucked away on the SAP help site:

1. Make sure to R-Click CRforVS6413SP35_0-80007712.EXE (or most recent SP) and install as admin.
2. Only install the CR (Crystal Reports, not Common Runtime) for VS. DO NOT install the runtime. Per the SAP installation instructions:

> As mentioned there, you must right click the Install Executable and select “Run as Administrator”.

> Installing the MSI will not fully integrate Crystal Reports into VS. MSI files by definition are for runtime distribution only. Do not run the MSI's on your Development PC, where VS is installed, not required.

[Crystal Reports, Developer for Visual Studio Downloads | SAP Help Portal](https://help.sap.com/docs/SUPPORT_CONTENT/crystalreports/3354091173.html)